# Search in data from cache

Tags: php, laravel

My question is, if there is data in the cache, I created a condition by saying fetch, and if not, I bring it from the database and refresh the cache for a certain period of time. Normally, if I don't use the cache, I can search the page, but I cannot search by id or nickname with the code below.So when using cache::get can I add a search condition?

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $submit = $request->get('submit');
        $id = $request->get('id');
        $nick_name = $request->get('nick_name');

        if (Cache::has('users')) {
            $users = Cache::get('users');
            return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
        }

        $users = User::when(!empty($id), function ($query) use ($id) {
            $query->where('id', $id);
        })->when(!empty($nick_name), function ($query) use ($nick_name) {
            $query->where('nick_name', $nick_name);
        })->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();


        Cache::put('users', $users, now()->addMinutes(60));
        return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
    }
```

Update: Based on the examples on the page below, the problem was solved
https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/caching-in-laravel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add search criteria in your cache key. E.g.

```php
public function index(Request $request) {
    $submit = $request->get('submit');
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $nick_name = $request->get('nick_name');

    $cacheKey = User::class . md5(json_encode([$submit, $id, $nick_name]));

    if (Cache::has($cacheKey)) {
    /* ... */
}
```

because now your cache writes only first search result and ignores everything else.

---

Or write to cache all users. Then run that array through `array_filter` applying filters. But that can be waste of developer time if search is very dynamic.

Comment: It's working now, but I'm asking to understand. When we say if(Cache::has($cacheKey)) , if there is only search, does it not look at the cache? @Justinas

Comment: @kennedyas `if (Cache::has())` looks for whatever key you specify. It does not process any filtering

Comment: What I want to say is this. When I enter any id value and log, it seems that this place does not work.if (Cache::has($cacheKey)) {$users = Cache::get('users');dd($users); because dd() returns no results. @Justinas

Comment: @kennedyas Because you should use `$cacheKey` in `Cache::get` too...

Comment: I used it but it still doesn't enter if. @Justinas

Comment: @kennedyas Did you use same key in `Cache::put` too?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't get data from cache in any way. If I do a search or normal listing, it comes directly from the sql query. @Justinas

Comment: You must enter the same search criteria in order to hit cache

Comment: Is there a page where you can post an example usage? @Justinas